# Greenmail SMTP server is not working properly as custom docker image

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, jakarta-mail

I was trying to start a greenmail server in a spring boot application and dockerize it so that I can use it as a local mail-mock-server to behavior test mailing functionality in my original application.

The docker image is working properly when started using `docker-compose up -d` command and endpoints tested from a REST client.

The issue happens when I try to connect it from my original application for testing purpose with the docker image running in a container.

Exception trace when I tried sending a mail to mock-server is added below.

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection
>   failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not
>   connect to SMTP host: 127.0.0.1, port: 8585, response: -1. Failed
>   messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP
>   host: 127.0.0.1, port: 8585, response: -1
>         at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:446)
>   ~[spring-context-support-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:359)
>   ~[spring-context-support-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:354)
>   ~[spring-context-support-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>         at com.test.controller.MailTestController.sendMail(MailTestController.java:80)
>   ~[main/:na]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
>         .......................................................................................................
>         .......................................................................................................
>
> Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 127.0.0.1, port: 8585, response: -1
>         at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2197)
>   ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
>         at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:740)
>   ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
>         at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366) ~[javax.mail-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
>         at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:515)
>   ~[spring-context-support-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:435)
>   ~[spring-context-support-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>         ... 100 common frames omitted

DockerFile configuration and docker-compose.yml of mail-mock-server are added below.

**DockerFile** :-

```
FROM gcr.io/distroless/java:latest

VOLUME /opt/test/

ARG JAR_FILE
COPY libs/mock-mail-server-*.jar /opt/test/mock-mail-server-app.jar
WORKDIR /opt/test/
CMD ["mock-mail-server-app.jar"]
```

**docker-compose.yml** :-

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: test/mock-mail-server:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    container_name: mock-mail-server-app
    ports: 
      - 0.0.0.0:8484:8484
      - 127.0.0.1:8585:8585
```

And the greenmail server is started in main class as follows.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MailMockServerApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MailMockServerApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public GreenMail greenMail() {
    GreenMail smtpServer = new GreenMail(new ServerSetup(8585, "127.0.0.1", "smtp"));
    smtpServer.setUser("test.mailer@test.com", "test", "test");
    smtpServer.start();
    return smtpServer;
  }
}
```

After building a docker image and starting the docker container using command `docker-compose up -d` I tried the below configurations for `JavaMailSender` bean in my original application's application.yml file.

```
mail:
    default-encoding: UTF-8
    host: ${MAIL_SERVER_HOST:127.0.0.1}
    username: ${MAIL_SERVER_USER_NAME:test}
    password: ${MAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD:test}
    port: ${MAIL_SERVER_PORT:8585}
    properties:
      mail:
        debug: true
        smtp:
          debug: false
          auth: true
          starttls: true
    protocol: smtp
    test-connection: false
```

Meanwhile, this works fine when my mock-mail-server application from command line using `java -jar` command. But when I try the same in docker it fails with connection exception.

Am I missing any other configuration in my original application or mock-server application?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From the point of view of your application, the SMTP service isn't running on `localhost`.

Comment: @DavidMaze : But when I checked using netstat the SMTP server is listening in port 8585. And the endpoints can be tested from a REST client.

Comment: You need to expose the port rather than 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 and expose it. inside docker it's local for docker container. so won't listen for code running on the host machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check after running the docker container if there is any service listening on the port you specified? There is netstat command for this [windows/linux]. If there is no service listening it'll give you can't connect to server error.

```
docker exec -ti <container> bash
```

can be used for linux like base images. Or try some verbose way logs from your smtp service.

The CMD one will be the only process running in a container unless it has a process manager in it.

It's not clear whether "it works when executed as java -jar" is when you try command CMD or outside docker on local machine. Can you please clarify.

As discussed in chat - 
The server is inside the container configured to listen on 127.0.0.1:8585 and you have exposed the same port on host. 
So to solve the issue

You need to configure your smtp server to listen on 0.0.0.0 as using 127.0.0.1 makes it listen to connection originating from inside container, for 127.0.0.1 of the container and 127.0.0.1 fo container is not same as the localhost of the host machine from where client is trying to connect.
So following changes will do -

```
 GreenMail smtpServer = new GreenMail(new ServerSetup(8585, "0.0.0.0", "smtp"));
```

and the application's config yaml file with

```
 host: ${MAIL_SERVER_HOST:0.0.0.0}
```

Though the docker-compose file config 127.0.0.1:8585:8585 can be changed to 8585:8585 to listen on all host addresses like port forwarding or host's ip other than loopback ip.

Comment: can you just update it in question? will be better for anybody else who's also trying to help you, can you see the port 8585 in local address - try netstat -tulpen

Comment: ok service is listening. But how's your code trying to conenct it? same container or form other container?

Comment: With this docker image running, I'm trying to connect it from another application started as a spring boot application. It is outside the container.

Comment: right. the IP of 127.0.0.1 is local inside container. so exposing won't solve the problem. It won't listen for external connection. Consider it like running your code in the VM you can listen on 0.0.0.0:8585 and expose it share the further issue

Comment: So what should be done to solve this ? It would be better if you can suggest configuration in my docker-compose.yml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184693/discussion-between-v-sukt-and-sachin).